# logstash fails to read correctly avro records from kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, avro

i'm trying to index data from kafka to ElasticSearch through logstash 
versions :
logstash : 6.2.4
elasticSearch : 6.2.4
kafka : 0.10
avro : 1.8.2
the problem is that logstash read correctly the avro schema ( at least that's what i think )  but every execution i see them in different order
 and the major problem is that some fields remain empty and the rest get each other data , so the documents in elasticsearch are not reliable and correct

PS: i checked some avro records, i converted them and i made sure the problem is not from them but at the level of logstash

Comment: You could use Kafka Connect Elasticsearch, which integrates with Confluent's Avro Schema Registry

Comment: Write to console from logstash with just problem records as input to debug

Comment: @sramalingam24 i'm writing to console and all the records are read incorrectly ( and every time they are read differently )

Comment: It's a bit off the topic but could you share how you configured logstash? I'm trying something similar. In my case, I couldn't properly read kafka message using avro codec. I tried both file-type and http-type schema uri option. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-avro.html#plugins-codecs-avro-schema_uri). But all I got was a FATAL log that starts with An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `type_sym' for nil:NilClass>